# Add COLORED text (my custom MBR)

Tags: assembly, x86, boot, bootloader, bios

I've written a program in assembly and converted the *.asm file into a *.bin file with NASM. After doing this, I replaced it to the first sector of my virtual harddrive (In vmWare).
I'm new in assembly (and also new at this forum). 
It will print a message on the screen after reboot.

1st line: you can now insert and install

2nd line: your new OS

3nd line: right now

My question is now: How can I print the text (JUST from line 2 for example) into another color? Maybe green... or red?

The rest of the code should stay in this normal white/grey color. I just want to change this one line!

It would be great if someone can EXPLAIN it how this works and WHY it works then (I hope it will :P), because I want to improve my assembly skills.

This is my code since right now:

```
; nasm -f bin test.asm -o test.bin

BITS 16
ORG     0x7c00                  

jmp start

start:
        mov ax,cs
        mov ds,ax
        mov si,msg          
        call print

print:
        push ax
        cld
next:
        mov al,[si]
        cmp al,0            
        je done             
        call printchar
        inc si              
        jmp next            
done:
        jmp $               

printchar:
        mov ah,0x0e         
        int 0x10           
        ret

msg:            db        "You can now insert and install ",13,10,"your new OS ",13,10,"right now ", 0

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
dw        0xaa55
```

Comment: Generally speaking, you need to change the video mode to some graphical mode and then output coloured characters.  [int 10h/ah=00h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm) with mode 3 might be what you want.  You can output characters with a given colour using [int 10h/ah=0Eh](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm).

Comment: thanks fuz, I'll now read a bit about this to understand. But Is there any way to include this into my code without splitting the "msg:" line?
And when I have to split the line in 3 lines, for example; then I don't konw on whitch place I have to include the comand.

Comment: You need to set up the video mode first before printing anything at all.  You only do this once.  Then, for each character you print, you pass the desired colour in `bl` as a number from 0 to 7. Try to experiment with this!

Comment: If you are dealing with an IBM-AT or  machine )or emulator) with EGA/VGA you should consider trying [Write String Int 10h/ah=13h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0210.htm)

Comment: `done:`
        `jmp $` should be placed (moved) after `call print`

Answer (score 2):

BIOS can display colored characters. See [Displaying characters with DOS or BIOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747002/displaying-characters-with-dos-or-bios) for many details.

> My question is now: How can I print the text (**JUST from line 2** for example) into another color? Maybe green... or red?
> The rest of the code should stay in this normal white/grey color. I just want to change this one line!

> But Is there any way to include this into my code **without splitting the "msg:" line**?

If you insist on staying in the text video mode 3 (16-color 80x25) then I suggest you look for the BIOS-related code snippets in the Q/A for which I have provided a link. In essence you would be executing back to back the BIOS.WriteCharacterAndAttribute function 09h with the BIOS.Teletype function 0Eh.

If you are prepared to switch to a graphics video mode like 18 (16-color 640x480), then the BIOS.Teletype function 0Eh *can* print colored characters on its own. Add next lines:

```
mov  ax, 0012h   ; BIOS.SetVideoMode 16-color 640x480
int  10h
```

The solution to *not* splitting that one *msg* line would be to insert the color information into the text prefixed by some escape character. I will be using the **%** sign for this purpose:

```
; IN (ds:si) OUT (si) MOD (ax,bx)
colorPrint:
    mov  bl, 07h  ; Default WhiteOnBlack 
    lodsb         ; String is not empty for sure
.a: cmp  al, '%'
    jne  .b       ; It is not our escape
    lodsb
    cmp  al, '%'  ; Use %% to print a single % character
    je   .b
    mov  bl, al   ; Setting a new color attribute
    jmp  .c
.b: mov  ah, 0Eh  ; BIOS.Teletype
    int  10h
.c: lodsb
    test al, al
    jnz  .a       ; Repeat while not at end-of-string
    ret
; ----------------
msg: db "You can now insert and install", 13, 10
     db "%", 02h, "your new OS", "%", 07h, 13, 10
     db "right now.", 0
```

From the above, only "your new OS" appears in green. The rest is shown in white.