# DosBox how to fix character attribute?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086, dosbox

I wrote my assembly code just to write a character with a blue background and white foreground. It works in emu8086's emulator but when I open it on DosBox it does not show the background color.

With Emu8086:
[image: With Emu8086]

With DosBox:
[image: Wtih DosBox]

```
mov ax,0012h
int 10h

mov ah,9
mov al,31h
mov bl,1fh
int 10h
```

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks for the reply, CX is non-zero in the emulator so it prints bunch of characters, but not with the background color i needed. It prints with black background. That problem only occurs in DosBox

Comment: @MichaelPetch No problem at all. I uploaded some screenshots for clearance sir.

Comment: First off are you intending to do this in graphics mode? (mode 12h is 16 color 640x480) (I suspect that EMU8086 is implementing things in a non standard way and DOSBox is handling it correctly).

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yeah, i do intend to do this in 640x480 pixel graphics mode. I want to know if the problem is general or not. If it is, i have to do more research about DosBox, maybe i have to change something in DosBox's configuration files.

Comment: In graphics mode set the background color separately with int 10h/ah=0bh. But that will change the background color for the entire screen.

Comment: @MichaelPetch That worked for my situation, thanks again for solving my problem.

Comment: You're not loading a character count into `cx` to set the number of characters to write.  I think the attribute byte (`bl`) only applies to the character (foreground) in graphic modes and does not change the background for the character.  `int 10h/ah=0bh` will set the background (pixel 0) color.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm So isn't there a register that change background color of a single character in graphics mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the graphics video modes, the `BL` parameter for BIOS function 09h only defines the foreground color. It is always applied to a black background.

Below is my implementation of an extension of the functionality of this function. Now `BL` holds an attribute (foreground color and background color) just like in the text video modes.

**<sup>only valid in a *graphics* video mode</sup>**

```
; IN (al,bl,cx) OUT ()
EnhancedWriteCharacterWithAttribute:
    pusha
    mov     bh, 0            ;Display page 0
    mov     bp, bx
    push    ax
    shr     bl, 4            ;Get background color (high nibble)
    mov     ax, 09DBh        ;ASCII DBh is full block character
    int     10h              ;BIOS.WriteCharacterAndAttribute
    xor     bx, bp           ;Anticipate upcoming 'xor'
    and     bl, 15           ;Get foreground color (low nibble)
    or      bl, 128          ;Have BIOS 'xor' it
    pop     ax
    int     10h              ;BIOS.WriteCharacterAndAttribute
    popa
    ret
```

Use it like this:

```
mov     ax, 0012h ; BIOS.SetVideo 640x480x16
int     10h

mov     al, "1"   ; Character
mov     bl, 1Fh   ; Attribute
mov     cx, 80    ; Repetition count
call    EnhancedWriteCharacterWithAttribute
```

#### Take note

In the text video modes providing a large repetition count in `CX` can write the whole screen at once. This is not possible in the graphics video modes because BIOS will stop at the right edge of the screen.

---

You might want to read [Displaying characters with DOS or BIOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747002/displaying-characters-with-dos-or-bios) for more on how to achieve your current and future goals.

Comment: Regarding this statement _This is not possible in the graphics video modes_ . Some BIOSes in a time long gone would be smart enough to wrap the output (even in graphics) while others didn't. The issue is that you couldn't rely on a specific behaviour so you essentially had to assume that there was no wrapping. That ended up being a BIOS implementation behaviour.