# How to get a emu8086 program to output a result?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, number-formatting, bios, emu8086

Here is my assignment:

> Write a program to divide two 8-bit numbers using successive subtraction method using 8086. Multiply this result with 7365. Display this result in Blue color on the output screen at row 19, column 14, page no. 0 using interrupts.

Here is my code:

```
; You may customize this and other start-up templates; 
; The location of this template is c:\emu8086\inc\0_com_template.txt

; You may customize this and other start-up templates;
; The location of this template is c:\emu8086\inc\0_com_template.txt

org 100h

dividend db 25; Example dividend
divisor db 5; Example divisor
result db 0; To store the quotient
remainder db 0; To store the remainder

main:
    mov ax, @data; Initialize the data segment
    mov ds, ax

    mov al, 16h; Load dividend into AL
    mov bl, 4h; Load divisor into BL
    xor ah, ah; Clear AH to store quotient
    xor dh, dh; Clear DH to store remainder

divide_loop:
    cmp al, bl; Compare AL and BL
    jl divide_done; Jump if AL < BL, division is done

    sub al, bl; Subtract BL from AL
    inc ah; Increment quotient

    jmp divide_loop; Repeat the loop

divide_done:
    mov 1000h, ah; Store quotient in memory
    mov 1001h, al; Store remainder in memory

mult:
    mov bx, 7365h
    mov ax, 1000h
    mul bx
    mov 1002h, ax

display_result:
    mov ah, 13h; Set interrupt for write string
    mov bh, 0; Set page number to 0
    mov bl, 0011_1011b; Set text color to white on black
    mov cx, 2; Set number of characters to write
    mov dl, 10; Set column position to 10
    mov dh, 19; Set row position to 19

    mov bx, 1002h; Point to the data to display
    mov es, bx; Set data segment for the string

    lea dx, [bx]; Load address of the string into DX

    int 10h; Call interrupt to write the string

end main

ret
```

The result is not getting displayed to screen.

I have sought help of Chatgpt and interrupts manual of 8086 to write this, I compiled this on emu8086 4.08

Comment: You need to use a debugger.

Comment: i tried using it, but no matter what i do it never displays a result, should i do some navigation through pages or something like that

Comment: EMU8086 has a debugger built-in that lets you single-step and look at the registers change.  Use that to look at what the code actually *is* doing, and to check register contents right before instructions like `int 10h` execute.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> org 100h
>
>  dividend db 25; Example dividend
>  divisor db 5; Example divisor
>  result db 0; To store the quotient
>  remainder db 0; To store the remainder
>
> main:
> ```

In emu8086, when mentioning `org 100h`, you will be creating an executable program with the .COM extension. In such a program execution starts with the first byte and that byte should be *code*, not *data* like is the case here! You must store those data defining lines much lower in the text, beneath all the code.

> ```
> int 10h; Call interrupt to write the string
>
> end main
>
> ret
> ```

In a .COM program there's also no need to include `main:` nor `end main`. It's noise.

> ```
> mov al, 16h; Load dividend into AL
> mov bl, 4h; Load divisor into BL
> ```

Better use the variables that were defined in the program. You write it like: `mov al, [dividend]` `mov bl, [divisor]`

> ```
> divide_done:
>  mov 1000h, ah; Store quotient in memory
>  mov 1001h, al; Store remainder in memory
> mult:
>  mov bx, 7365h
>  mov ax, 1000h
>  mul bx
>  mov 1002h, ax
> ```

The multiplication is wrong. Because `mov ax, 1000h` **is not using the quotient that is stored in memory**. This instruction just loads the immediate value 1000h (4096). Why would it operate any different from the instruction `mov bx, 7365h` that is directly above?
You need to dereference by using the square brackets like in `mov ax, [1000h]`. But wait, since you have stored the remainder from the division at address 1001h, you should not be reading a full word from the memory! You can use instead: `mov al, [1000h]` `mov ah, 0`.

Once your multiplication produced its **32**-bit result in DX:AX, and you stored only the lowest 16 bits in memory at 1002h, you still need to convert the value into a corresponding string of characters. See [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos) for a complete primer on doing that.

Since your assignment wants you to display these characters at a specific position on the screen (14,19) and using the BlueOnBlack attribute (01h), you can't rely on (colorless) DOS, but need to use a suitable BIOS function. The one that you have selected *can* do the job, but you got most of its arguments totally wrong! Did you consult a reference at least?
[Displaying characters with DOS or BIOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747002/displaying-characters-with-dos-or-bios) is another primer that amongst other things, explains and shows how to output colorful text using BIOS. The *WriteStringWithAttributeTVM* code snippet should be of special interest for you. It accepts 2 arguments: in BL the attribute (01h for BlueOnBlack) and in SI the address of the first character in the string that corresponds to the product that you have calculated.

```
org  100h
mov  ax, data
mov  ds, ax
mov  al, [dividend]
mov  bl, [divisor]

...

mult:
 mov  bx, 7365h
 mov  al, [result]
 mov  ah, 0
 mul  bx             ; -> DX:AX

 ...        < add conversion code based on the 1st link >

 mov  bl, 01h
 mov  si, OFFSET buffer
 call WriteStringWithAttributeTVM
 ret

 ...        < add WriteStringWithAttributeTVM from the 2nd link >

 dividend  db 25 ; Example dividend
 divisor   db 5  ; Example divisor
 result    db 0  ; To store the quotient
 remainder db 0  ; To store the remainder
 buffer    db 32 dup 0
```