# Get linear address of FS:[0] in 32-bit protected mode / MSVC inline asm

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

I used this instruction in Visual C++ inline assembly

```
lea eax, FS:[0]
```

Why did `eax` get a zero?

And how do I get the linear address of `FS:[0]`?

Comment: Updated to ask [what the OP really wanted to know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction/47589203?noredirect=1#comment82135841_47589203)

Comment: Normally, some type of operating system call is needed to map such an address into a process / thread's flat virtual address space.

Comment: In 64-bit mode, use [`RDFSBASE eax`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/RDFSBASE:RDGSBASE.html) if it's available on your CPU.  But unfortunately that instruction is not available in 32-bit mode, and it's not baseline for x86-64 either; there's a CPUID feature bit for it.  (And using MSVC inline-asm restricts you to only 32-bit code.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming FS points to the Windows [Thread Information Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) (TIB), also known as the Thread Environment Block (TEB), you get the linear address of the TIB by reading the 32-bit value at `fs:[0x18]`. The best way to do this in Visual C++ is to use the [`__readfsdword`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3887zk1s.aspx) intrinsic:

```
TEB *teb = (TEB *) __readfsdword(0x18);
```

Comment: you have solved my problem. I want to know the linear address of TEB, so I try to use `LEA` instruction.

Answer (score 3):

The `LEA` instruction ("Load Effective Address") is badly named (e.g. should probably be called `LEO`/"Load Effective Offset") because it only calculates the offset within a segment.

Comment: do you know how get the address of FS:[0] in Visual Studio C++?

Comment: @ZhiboShen: Sorry, no (I'm mostly a "bare metal assembly language" programmer I guess).