# ASM what do [] do exactly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qS4VWL5R_OM&list=PLhixgUqwRTjxglIswKp9mpkfPNfHkzyeN&index=8) but I got stuck. He starts explaining at about 6:30.
So there is a for loop in that episode that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYC02.png). And I got lost during the explanation as he said. But I rewatched it a couple of times and there is one thing I don't understand. So this is the code and I took some notes while watching the registers.
`mov     rax, [rbp+arg]`
So after this line rax = 0x7ffe63c2d498 and arg = 0x7ffe63c2d380 . I decoded these two but nothing comes up so I'm assuming they are pointers.
`add     rax, 8`
`mov     rdx, [rax]`
After this line rdx = 0x7ffe63c2e09d . I'm assuming this is a pointer again.
`mov     eax, [rbp+i]`
This moves the value of i in eax for example 0x01
`cdqe`
`add     rax, rdx`
Here you add the value of i to the pointer of the string.
`movzx   eax, byte ptr [rax]`
Here you move the character that the rax was pointing to into eax.
`movsx   eax, al`
`add     [rbp+sum], eax`
`add     [rbp+i], 1`
Here you sum up and i++.

My question is: aren't [] supposed to move the value that the address points to into the register? So it moves the value arg is pointing to into rax and then the value rax is pointing to into rdx. But both of these are pointers. How come? So arg is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: Yes,  as you can clearly see and should also know, `argv` has type `char*[]` and the compiler decided to copy it to the stack which is accessed through a pointer again.

Comment: assembler doesn't have data types in the sense that `C` does. There are no pointers in assembler. There are only registers and immediate operands. The instruction dictates how the value of a register or immediate is interpreted by that instruction.

Comment: Ah so arg is the pointer to the argv array? Then the char* argv[1] pointer is copied into rdx? And then it searches to the index of the char* and gets the character?

Comment: @bolov but you can still think of them as pointers? They point to a value that is accessed with []?

Comment: `arg` is an offset relative to `rbp` which accesses the copy of the `argv` on the stack.

Comment: @GregorTrplan sort of. Only in the context of an instruction. The instruction gives meaning to the value. For instance `mov eax rdi`. Here the value of `rdi` is just a number. It doesn't have any meaning. But in `mov eax [rdi]` here `rdi` is interpreted as an address in memory.

Comment: Ah so the actual argv is on the stack and you can access it via rbp? But the things after that I wrote in the previous comment are correct?

Comment: @bolov aha thanks for clearing up that. I'm quite new to asm so I don't understand a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

Assembly doesn't have data types in the sense that C does. There are no pointers in assembly. There are only registers and immediate operands. The instruction dictates how the value of a register or immediate is interpreted by that instruction.

> but you can still think of them as pointers? They point to a value
>   that is accessed with []?

Sort of. Only in the context of an instruction and only for you.

For instance `mov eax rdi`. Here the value of `rdi` is interpreted just like a number. For you, who are trying to understand the algorithm it could mean a counter, or a sum, or an offset, or a pointer. For the instruction however it's just a number.

But in `mov eax [rdi]` here `rdi` is interpreted as an address in memory.

In `lea eax, [rsi + rdi]` here the value of `rsi + rdi` is interpreted as a memory address. But for you this instruction just computes `rsi + rdi` so it really could mean anything to you, the sum of a pointer and an offset, or the sum of two integers. But that is just the meaning you put to them to understand the algorithm.

To answer your question `[OP]` means "the value found in memory at address `OP`".

`lea eax, [rsi + rdi]` means "load in eax the effective address of the value found in memory at address `rsi + rdi`" which is just `rsi + rdi`

Comment: Ok I kind of understand but I still have some questions. So in `mov eax [rdi]`  the `rdi` is interpreted as a memory address and the value it points to is moved into `eax`? Also in the last paragraph something is unclear. Is `lea eax, [rsi + rdi]` the same as `add rsi, rdi` `lea eax rsi` or `lea eax [rsi]`? Because you said it just computes `rsi + rdi`. Doesn't it also treat it as an address and copies the value it points to to `eax`?

Comment: @GregorTrplan `lea` is the one exception.  `lea` computes the address and then writes the address to the other operand.  No memory is accessed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction

Comment: I tried to read the question but it kinda makes my head hurt. As I said why not use the add and mov instruction instead of lea?

Comment: @GregorTrplan that is answered very well in the question I linked. Read the 2nd most voted answer.

Comment: if you want to learn assembly use https://godbolt.org/ a lot. Like a lot a lot. :)

Comment: @Gregor - In addition to the linked answer: At the time when LEA was introduced it was performed by a separate "address generation unit", freeing up the main part of the CPU to start working on the next instruction. Another bonus.