# LEAL and MOVL in machine instruction

Tags: c, machine-code

what is the difference between following machine codes??

> > movl 8(%ebp), %ecx
> >
> > leal 8(%ebp), %ecx

can someone explain this to me???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction)

Comment: You should specify which CPU type you are using — I'd guess it is an Intel chip of some sort, but you should include the information in the question.  It is also not clear why you think 'assembler' or 'machine code' questions should be tagged with C — it isn't directly C code in any meaningful sense.

Answer (score 2):

The first *fetches* the 32 bit value pointed to by `8(%ebp)`.

The latter computes the flat *address*.

Thus, in C, given `int x = 0;` and it is located at `8(%ebp)` (i.e. `x` is in the stack frame of the function):

The first is `int y = x;`

The latter is `int *z = &x;`

In machine code [for most/many architectures, such as `x86`--but *not* all (e.g. `mc68000`)] registers are the same regardless of whether they contain a value or address.