# x86 asm: How to set a reg to a non-SIB supported offset?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I have an array `a` of 24 byte structs, arranged without padding so that struct 1 begins 24 bytes after struct 0 (`(void*) &a[1] == ((void*) &a[0]) + 24`.

`rbx` holds the index of the struct.  I'd like to set `rdi` to `a + rbx*24` and `rsi` to `a + rbx*24 + 8`.  SIB does not allow multiplying by 24.  How should I do this?

(x86, 64 bits, assembly).

Comment: Use multiple instructions. E.g. use a `lea rbx, [rbx+2*rbx]` to multiply by 3 first, then do the remaining `8*rbx` to get to 24.

Comment: Address arithmetic is just arithmetic after all, and your CPU has a full complement of arithmetic instructions, so don't be afraid to use them.  If you couldn't think of anything better, there would always be `imul rbx, 24`.  But as Sep points out, you can in fact do better in this case.

Comment: Note that ISO C doesn't define address math on `void*`.  Probably you mean `(char*)`, or `(uintptr_t)`.  As an extension, GNU C *does* let you do `24 + (void*)foo`, working like `char*`

Comment: You can ask a compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/jhbET64Ee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `RDI` and `RSI` without even changing the index in `RBX`.

```
lea  rsi, [rbx + rbx*2]    ; RSI = RBX * 3
lea  rdi, [a + rsi*8]      ; RDI = a + (RBX * 3) * 8
lea  rsi, [rdi + 8]        ; RSI = a + (RBX * 3) * 8 + 8
```

[What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction/1660429#1660429)

Comment: Why leave the `+8` for a separate instruction?  If you can use `a` as an absolute signed disp32, you can use `a+8`.  Oh, I see, because the question for some weird reason wanted both pointers actually materialized in separate registers.  Perhaps as args for some function?  Otherwise just use `[rdi]` and `[rdi+8]` addressing modes for accessing memory.  Or even `[a + rsi*8]` and `[a * rsi*8 + 8]`, although that takes more space.

Comment: Yes, the pointers are each args to a function call.