# base index addressing of array in NASM

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, nasm, addressing-mode

This is my nasm code:

```
extern fprintf
extern printf
extern stdout

section .data
    mas dw 1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4,4, 5,5,5,5,5, 6,6,6,6,6, 7,7,7,7,7
    fmtstr db "%d", 10, 0

section .text
    global main
main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp,rsp

    mov esi, 2
    mov eax, [mas + esi * 20]

    mov rdi, fmtstr
    mov rsi, rdx
    mov rax, 0
    call printf

leave
ret
```

all I want is to get in eax mas[2], where each element of array consists of 5 int, so it is 20 bytes
But nasm complains about [mas + esi * 20]: error: invalid effective address

Comment: [x86 asm: How to set a reg to a non-SIB supported offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70186421) shows how to do manual address math if your scale factor isn't 1, 2, 4, or 8.  But how do you expect EAX (a 4-byte register) to hold 20 bytes of data?  You'll get the first 2 words of the struct.  Also, prefer 64-bit addressing modes like `[mas + rsi]` not `esi`.  (e.g. `mov esi,2` / `lea eax, [rsi + rsi*4]` / `mov eax, [mas + rax * 2]` like a compiler would use, look at https://godbolt.org/).

Comment: The rest of your code doesn't make much sense either; you copy RDX (which still holds `envp`) to the 2nd arg of `printf("%d\n", envp)`, not using your EAX load result.

Comment: @PeterCordes I mean that struct in all consists 20 bytes and I just need 4 bytes for each int to change it

Comment: Ok, if that's what you're trying to do, it's an exact duplicate, not also or instead some other design bug.  Since this is x86-64, you could use RAX to load 4x `short` word-sized integers.  (`int` is 4 bytes in standard x86-64 ABIs, like System V which you're using.  You used `dw` which emits in units of 2-byte words, rather than `dd` for dwords.)

Comment: @PeterCordes it was my experiments, in main prog I use `dd`. Thank u for your link to answer, coz English isn't my native, so idk how will my question be in eng.