# How do MOV and LEA interact with each other? Assembler

Tags: assembly, x86

at the moment i try to get a bit closer to assembler programming and therefore looked at the assembler code of an easy hello world program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () 
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("Hello, world!\n");
    }    
}
```

Now i try to understand how a fiew simple assembler commands work while going step by step through the assembler code and analyzing what exactly happens:

```
0x55555555515c <main+19>:   jmp    0x555555555171 <main+40>
   0x55555555515e <main+21>:    lea    rax,[rip+0xe9f]        # 0x555555556004
   0x555555555165 <main+28>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x555555555168 <main+31>:    call   0x555555555050 <puts@plt>
   0x55555555516d <main+36>:    add    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
   0x555555555171 <main+40>:    cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x9
   0x555555555175 <main+44>:    jle    0x55555555515e <main+21>
   0x555555555177 <main+46>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x55555555517c <main+51>:    leave  
   0x55555555517d <main+52>:    ret
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how these two functions interact:

```
0x55555555515e <main+21>:   lea    rax,[rip+0xe9f]        # 0x555555556004
0x555555555165 <main+28>:   mov    rdi,rax
```

It would be great if someone could help me understand these specific lines :)

**Thanks!**

I was looking for information, but I still couldn't figure out why the record looks like this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction

Comment: They interact via the `rax` register.  The first one sets `rax` and the second uses `rax`.

Comment: You forgot to enable optimization so GCC wastes instructions generating the address in RAX and then has to copy it to RDI.  Re: the RIP-relative LEA itself: [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012)