# What are fast LEA and slow LEA unit in the microarchitecture of Inte's CPU?

Tags: intel, processor, microprocessors

I saw haswell's microarchitecture from below link mentioned that some pipelines can carry on fast LEA and some can run slow LEA, what's the meaning of fast LEA and slow LEA here? Related to LEA instruction? The search results are usually biases to LEA instruction, and don't lead to direct answer.

http://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most dedicated ALU units exist only on part of the execution ports (with constant changes being made from generation to generation), the CPU has to pick one of the possible ports according to the instruction (or rather the micro-operation) being performed. When Multiple identical ports can do the same, it should attempt to do some balancing, and there may be other possible factors. The exact algorithm of course is never published.

In this case however, the LEA operations are split into slow and fast ones, according to [this link](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/amplifier/lin/ug_docs/GUID-27C43896-1573-41F4-A8B4-E2E97E7D8A4D.htm), the slow ones are due to using 3 operand LEAs (base, index, offset). It actually also provides you with a performance monitor to measure how many such cases you encounter.

Comment: thanks. I am interested in why LEA is separated from ALU, since it is just sort of ALU operation (mostly add?)

Comment: @Thomson - *Mostly*, but not *completely*, it's much more complicated due to the extra source and therefore I believe it uses a dedicated execution unit - probably the same one that's usually reserved for memory operands (since it's already there and capable of doing that computation). A simple Add/Sub ALU probably can't cope with that. See also this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11389785/2016408

Comment: @Thomson and Leeor: LEA runs on normal ALU execution ports, not the AGUs in load ports or Haswell's port-7 store-AGU.  LEA has 2 register inputs and an immediate, like `vshufps xmm, xmm, xmm, 1` for example. ([Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](//stackoverflow.com/q/46597055)) 2-component LEA can run on multiple ports, 3-component only on one port.  (That changes with Ice Lake, see https://uops.info/.  But also, having a scale factor at all, even with just 2 components, makes it slower on recent Intel.  But still at least 2 execution ports can handle those "slow" LEAs)

Comment: Also [x86-64 do address calculating mov i.e mov i(r, r, i), r execute on on port 1? Or is it still p0156?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63975049) - kind of the reverse question.  And the next page of the Haswell RWT writeup (https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/5/) shows the load/AGU execution units on ports 2, 3, and the store-AGU on port 7.