# Why is the "mov" with complex addressing faster than the corresponding "lea"?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, instruction-set

I looked up in the [instruction tables](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) and found that in Coffee Lake, the RThroughput of the `lea` with 3 components is `1`. I think it’s very slow, so I guessed that the RThroughput of the `mov` with complex addressing is greater than `1`. To my surprise, the `mov` with complex addressing is actually faster than `lea`, which confuses me a lot.

Below is the test code I used. My computer’s microarchitecture is Comet Lake, which is not much different from Coffee Lake.

```
; 8 * 10^9 cycles
mov ecx, 1000000000
xor rax, rax
sub rsp, 40
.align 32
loop:
    lea r8, [rsp + rax + 4]
    lea r9, [rsp + rax + 8]
    lea r10, [rsp + rax + 12]
    lea r11, [rsp + rax + 16]
    lea r12, [rsp + rax + 20]
    lea r13, [rsp + rax + 24]
    lea r14, [rsp + rax + 28]
    lea r15, [rsp + rax + 32]
    sub ecx, 1
    jnz loop
add rsp, 40
```

```
; 4 * 10^9 cycles
mov ecx, 1000000000
xor rax, rax
sub rsp, 40
.align 32
loop:
    mov r8d, DWORD PTR [rsp + rax + 4]
    mov r9d, DWORD PTR [rsp + rax + 8]
    mov r10d, DWORD PTR [rsp + rax + 12]
    mov r11d, DWORD PTR [rsp + rax + 16]
    mov r12d, DWORD PTR [rsp + rax + 20]
    mov r13d, DWORD PTR [rsp + rax + 24]
    mov r14d, DWORD PTR [rsp + rax + 28]
    mov r15d, DWORD PTR [rsp + rax + 32]
    sub ecx, 1
    jnz loop
add rsp, 40
```

Comment: Maybe because `mov` uses different circuit to evaluate address than `lea`. `mov` goes to one of LOAD execution ports (port2 or port3), so two `mov`s can be executed in parallel. 3-component `lea` evaluates address with single ALU port (port1).

Comment: The good news is that Ice Lake made 3-component `lea` fast too

Comment: LEA uses an ALU, not the AGUs that are part of load ports (or the dedicated store-AGU on port 7 on Haswell / Skylake, or the two store AGUs on Ice Lake).   https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/5/  . See also https://uops.info/ for better instruction tables.

Comment: [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46597055) . Also [What is the "EU" in x86 architecture? (calculates effective address?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/791798) - Andy Glew was one of the architects of Intel's P6 microarchitecture (PPro), and he's correctly describing the fact that address-generation-unit execution units are separate from ALU execution units.  Intel (other than in-order Atom) doesn't run LEA on AGUs at all.  A highly-voted answer on [LEA or ADD instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6323027) is only correct for K8/K10

Comment: Found a nearly exact duplicate: [x86-64 do address calculating mov i.e mov i(r, r, i), r execute on on port 1? Or is it still p0156?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63975049) is asking about the same generation of Intel CPUs you have (Haswell through Skylake), so the port numbers mentioned in my answer apply to your CPU.  (That Q&A also mentions Ice Lake, which beefs up the store-AGU ports.)